# Payflow Link Returl URL error

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

I am integrating payflow link in a website.

I have a complex return URL to which the payflow link has to redirect after the user has a successful payment. the url is of kind

```
www.example.com/index.php?controller=main&data=no&detail=on
```

the problem is that when payflow redirects the user it replaces & with & amp; and the url becomes some thing like this

```
www.example.com/index.php?controller=main&amp;data=no&amp;detail=on
```

which crashes the framework because it arranges $_REQUEST parameters as follows

```
$_REQUEST['amp;data'] = no AND $_REQUEST['amp;detail'] = on
```

what should be done to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This will only happen if you are trying to set `RETURNURL` programatically. If you set this value inside of the manager account's hosted checkout pages settings it will not.

This is because the variables you pass to the payflow server are going to get `urlencoded`. To get around this include a length on your variable:

```
RETURNURL[66]=http://www.example.com/index.php?controller=main&data=no&detail=on
```

Comment: When i didnot send the URL with the length earlier it clipped all the details. So i am sending the url with length details and it is changing & to &amp\; The problem is the url is dynamic, I cant save it in Manager.

Comment: Strange, because I ran the test exactly like this and did not have problems recovering the get variables with `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`.. could you post the output of your `$_REQUEST['QUERY_STRING']` once they land back on the page??